# Vb Net Concatenated Double Data Type

Tags: vb.net, double, session-variables

Here's a weird one that I eventually solved but I'm hoping somebody can explain to me why it happened:

```
Public Function s(ByVal SesVarName As String, Optional ByVal SesVal As String = Nothing)
    
    If SesVal IsNot Nothing Then System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("" & SesVarName & "") = SesVal 
    If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("" & SesVarName & "") Is Nothing Then s = Nothing : Exit Function
    s = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("" & SesVarName & "")

End Function

s("A",2)
s("B",2) 
DIM num as Double = s("A") + s("B")
```

In the case above, num is returning 22 but when I hit it with a bigger hammer (below), I can get num to return 4... Weird huh?

```
s("A",2)
s("B",2) 
Dim num1 as Double = s("A")
Dim num2 as Double = s("B")
DIM num as Double = num1 + num2
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the session variables and how I'm using a function to declare them. What did I miss/mess up with the function? Is it a matter of being *too clever for my own good?* It seems to be working elsewhere, not that that really means anything.

I guess my main question is: shouldn't declaring num as Double prevent concatenation? Pointers on the function would be appreciated as well.

Am I overthinking it? Should I just start trying to find reasons to concatenate Double data types now that know I can?

Thanks

Comment: The type of the variable is irrelevant. The right hand side is executed first. The chinstrap happens first and it's only when the result of that is assigned to the variable that the conversion to Double occurs. You should start by turning Option Strict On.

Comment: Ah I see... and since the resulting value '22' is still technically double, it doesn't throw an error when concatenating.  Cool. Thanks for the explanation.  I'll look at Option Strict because I've seen it mentioned a few times but haven't learned about it yet. I'm a self taught Google programmer-- meaning I Google everything until I get it solved.

Comment: "22" is the strings "2" and "2" concatenated; 4 is the numbers 2 and 2 added. Without declaring the variable types, VB.NET will guess what the variable types are, which may or may not be the same as you thought they would be. Option Strict On stops it from guessing and tells you where the problems are.

Comment: Additionally to Andrew's comment, the `+` operator can operate as a numeric addition or as a string concatenation.  Unlike C#, VB has a separate string concatenation operator `&` that I would generally recommend to use when you want concatenation (but that doesn't help with avoiding concatenation when you want addition).